# React application with users roles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, redux, react-router

I started working with React/Redux about 2 months ago and I want to make an application with user roles. When a user logs in I want to change my Route component:

```
<Route path={"/"} component={MainPage}></Route>
```

To component

```
<Route path={"/"} component={MainPageUser}></Route>
```

If admin

```
<Route path={"/"} component={MainPageAdmin}></Route>
```

But if I make a switch with my Router I get the error

```
Warning: [react-router] You cannot change <Router routes>; it will be ignored
```

I want make access based on the type of account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to create a single component for the `/` path, and within that component return a different component based on the user role.

```
<Route path={"/"} component={Home} userRole={userRole}></Route>

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.userRole === "admin" ? <HomeAdmin /> : <HomeVisitor />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it a good approach to a system which can have many different types (more than 10) of user ?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you rootPageComponent wrapping the switchs.

How about this?

(Below is a just simple sample code. Please note that it does not work correctly)

```
<Route path={"/"} component={RootPage}></Route>
```

---

```
// RootPage.js
export default const RootPage({role}) => {
    switch(role) {
        case USER: return <MainPageUser />
        case ADMIN: return <AdminPage />
        default: return <MainPage />
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont work for me but Brett DeWoody code work correctly

Comment: Do u know how make ii more safely? I have a huge problem with user login and i cant find solution for this problem